# re render tabel get json vuejs

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, render

how to render a table after an update delete or insert action here I have a table using the following code

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="(item, index) in DATASKILL" :key="item.ID">
    <td>{{ index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.skills }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.profiency }}</td>
    <td class="text-xs-center">
  </tr>
</tbody>



 export default {
    data: function() {
     return {
       item: {
        skills: "",
        profiency: "",
        idusers : parseInt(localStorage.getItem("userId")),
      },
      };
    },
    computed: {
    DATASKILL() {
        return this.$store.state.skill //call json using axios in store 
      },
    },
    methods:{
     Submited() {
          this.$store
            .dispatch("createSkills", this.item)
            .then((response) => {
              // setTimeout(()=>{
    
              // this.$store.dispatch('getSkill') // load response json use action get in store
              // },2000)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              error;
            });
        },
     }
```

when I insert data using the modal form, how do I make the table render without being refreshed?

Comment: Since you are using computed, It should automatically load the table if there is any change

Comment: Can you share the missing part of the code